# Join query Symfony 1.4.11/Propel 1.4.2

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel

I've following query to execute

```
SELECT m.*, s.momento_idmember, sd.id_send, d.momento_id
FROM `momento_send` s,
    `send_distribution` sd,
    `momento_distribution` d,
    `momento` m
WHERE
    s.momento_idmember=6 AND
    sd.id_send=s.id AND
    sd.id_distribution=d.id AND
    d.momento_id=m.id;
```

MySQL 5.5.24 have proper relationship between tables.

Can someone please suggest how to achieve this query through Criteria (or whatever best for that) in propel. I'm trying it since 2+ hours without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go onto something like this:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->clearSelectColumns();
$c->addSelectColumn(MomentoSendPeer::MOMENTO_IDMEMBER);
$c->addSelectColumn(SendDistributionPeer::ID_SEND);
$c->addSelectColumn(MomentoDistributionPeer::MOMENTO_ID);

$c->addJoin(SendDistributionPeer::ID_SEND, MomentoSendPeer::ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$c->addJoin(SendDistributionPeer::ID_DISTRIBUTION, MomentoDistributionPeer::ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$c->addJoin(MomentoDistributionPeer::MOMENTO_ID, MomentoPeer::ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);

$c->add(MomentoSendPeer::MOMENTO_IDMEMBER, 6);
```

I don't think you can select `m.*` using propel 1.4. So you will have to add all field manually.

Comment: Thanks @j0k It is working for my earlier question. However can you help with how to select few columns from each table, I updated required SQL in question. I know I'm making things complicated but my ultimate goal is performance and for that, I'm just trying to minimize DB hits.

Comment: Thank you a lot @j0k Its 3-4th time you saved a lot of my time during this week only.